# get work days function to return whole number on sunday

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The function number_of_days(start_date, end_date) should calculate how manny work days are in between start_date and end_date. It wroks for whatever start_date as long it is not **sunday**.

Calculation has 3 steps:

1. take number of days before whole week (whole week can be 0 for small range dates like 21th - 24th)
2. then it adds whole weeks
3. takes all days that are leftover after whole week and add them up.

i need 2nd step to to produce whole number like 0, 5, 10, instead i get 0,7142857142857142857142857142857142857 on this example, because start_date parameter is sunday.

I could use ROUND() to solve it, but perhaps there is a better way?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_of_days(start_date IN DATE, end_date IN DATE)
    RETURN  NUMBER
    
    IS  v_number_of_days NUMBER;
        first_week_day DATE := TO_DATE('31-12-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
    
    BEGIN
--step 1
    SELECT  ( CASE  WHEN MOD(start_date - first_week_day, 7) BETWEEN 2 AND 5
                    THEN 6 - MOD(start_date - first_week_day, 7)
                    ELSE 0  END )
            +
--step 2
            ((  CASE  WHEN MOD(end_date - first_week_day, 7) < 7
                      THEN end_date - MOD(end_date - first_week_day, 7)
                      ELSE end_date  END )
              -
              ( CASE  WHEN MOD(start_date - first_week_day, 7) > 1
                      THEN start_date + 8 - MOD(start_date - first_week_day, 7)
                      ELSE start_date  END ) + 1
            ) / 7 * 5
            +
--step 3
            ( CASE  WHEN MOD(end_date - first_week_day, 7) BETWEEN 1 AND 6
                    THEN CASE   WHEN MOD(end_date - first_week_day, 7) = 6
                                THEN MOD(end_date - first_week_day, 7) - 1
                                ELSE MOD(end_date - first_week_day, 7) END
                    ELSE 0 END  )
    INTO    v_number_of_days
    FROM    DUAL;
    
    RETURN  v_number_of_days;
    
    END;
    

--test
    SELECT  number_of_days(TO_DATE('21-11-2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY'), TO_DATE('24-11-2021', 'DD-MM-YYYY'))
    FROM    DUAL;
```

Comment: Where in all of this does `javascript` play a role?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're just making this too complicated...
First of all, it's better to work with in ISO weeks: it starts from Monday.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions230.htm
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79

So you can easily get first day of ISO week using `trunc(dt, 'IW')`. For example, 19th of November is Friday and we can easily get the first day of this week using `trunc(date'2021-11-19','IW')`:

```
SQL> select trunc(date'2021-11-19','IW') xx from dual;

XX
-------------------
2021-11-15 00:00:00
```

So 2021-11-15 is Monday.

Now let's imagine we got some dates:

```
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
           X  X  X  X
  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
  X  X  X  X  X  X  X
  X  X
```

We can easily get number of working days in full weeks (count_full_weeks * 5/7), so let's exclude them:

```
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
           X  X  X  X
  X  X
```

Then, let's transform it graphically, since we know that the number of remaining days will always be less than 7 days (less than a week) and the first day will be one of the first 7 days:

```
 Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
           X  X  X  X  X  X
```

Let's replace Mo,Tu,We... with their numbers:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
           X  X  X  X  X  X
```

Since we know that number of days in this partial week can't be 7, we know that the latest end will be:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  0  1  2  3  4  5  6
 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
                    X  X  X  X  X  X
```

Now let's replace numbers of the second week to 7-13:

```
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
                    X  X  X  X  X  X
```

Now we can understand that we need to check just for 5th and 6th days, ie to check if our period contains 5 and 6.

So it will be like this (I've detailed as much as possible):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_of_days(start_date IN DATE, end_date IN DATE)
    RETURN  NUMBER
as
    days_between        int;
    full_weeks          int;
    remaining_days      int;
    remaining_workdays  int;
    
    v_first_week_day    date;
    v_start             int;
    v_end               int;
    
    result              int;
begin
    days_between := end_date - start_date;
    full_weeks := trunc(days_between/7);
    remaining_days:= mod(days_between,7); -- or days_between-full_weeks*7
    
    v_first_week_day := trunc(start_date,'IW');
    v_start := start_date - v_first_week_day;
    v_end := v_start + remaining_days - 1;
    
    remaining_workdays := remaining_days
                        - case when 5 between v_start and v_end then 1 else 0 end
                        - case when 6 between v_start and v_end then 1 else 0 end
                        ;
    result := full_weeks * 5 + remaining_workdays;
    RETURN result;
end;
/
```

I did it with a lot of sub-steps and intermediate calculations and variables, just to make it more clear. Obviously, you can make it much shorter, for example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION number_of_days(start_date IN DATE, end_date IN DATE)
    RETURN  NUMBER
as
begin
    return 5*trunc((end_date-start_date)/7) + mod((end_date-start_date),7) 
     - case when 5-(start_date - trunc(start_date,'IW')) between 0 and mod((end_date-start_date),7)-1 then 1 else 0 end
     - case when 6-(start_date - trunc(start_date,'IW')) between 0 and mod((end_date-start_date),7)-1 then 1 else 0 end
    ;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started as I don't understand your requirements.

```
with time_between as (
  select trunc ( timestamp'2021-06-14 06:00:00' ) - 
           trunc ( timestamp'2021-06-08 14:00:00' ) t
  from   dual
)
  select *
  from   time_between;

T   
   6
```